# Libgdx Positioning objects on same position in all resolutions

Tags: android, android-layout, graphics, opengl-es, libgdx

I'm newbie in libgdx trying to make a live wallpaper. 
The issue is positioning of object in all screen size with different resolutions in android.
I'm using Orthographic Camera and FillViewport to support multiple screens using viewport https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports.[enter link description here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports)

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera();
  viewPort = new FillViewport(WORLD_WIDTH/1.1f,(WORLD_HEIGHT),camera);
  viewPort.apply();
  camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth/2, camera.viewportHeight/2, 0);
```

where

```
WORLD_WIDTH=2048;
WORLD_HEIGHT = 1325;
```

I want to place an object on same position in different screens Like balloon on top of each screen. For this I tried to find percentage of height in given WORLD and on basis of that percentage I found hieght on screen but it appears different position ondifferent screens some time in middle of screen some time in bottom, some time on top and some type out of screen. :-( while I'm trying to place always on same height as it was in WORLD height. I used following code to compute that

```
balloonHeight = (((Gdx.graphics.getHeight()*1.0f)/WORLD_HEIGHT)) *
                (WORLD_HEIGHT-(ballonSprite.getHeight()*((Gdx.graphics.getHeight()*1.0f)/WORLD_HEIGHT)));
```

ballonSprite.setY(balloonHeight);

I will be thankful to all of you kindly let me know issue and help me to understand what mistake I'm making.

Comment: You are already using the right things, `Viewport` and `Camera`. But instead of using such big values for world width and height, you should think about them as "meters" or something you can imagine in real life. If you want to see 20m of the world at one time on screen, your `WORLD_WIDTH` is 20. Also your entities size should then be given in meters, a human-like character, for example, would be about 1.8 heigh.

Comment: If you are using a Viewport other than ScreenViewport, then `Gdx.graphics.getHeight()` should have no place in your calculation at all.